# VritualBox Windows Guest Corruption and File retrieval?

Tags: virtualbox

I am having some troubles with a windows VM on virtualbox and I am looking for some help to get files off the desktop. I have tried all I can think of.

The background here is I tried opening Visio this morning, and it said `Microsoft Office has run into problems` and could not get it to open at all, tried repairing, reinstalling, no office program would work. I have several visio and excel documents on the VM that I need to now get off the VM.

My problems are numerous:

- Vbox guest additions won't install due to a completely unique error: `ERROR (0000000d): The data is invalid.`
- Dragging files from the VM to the host does not work, error: `The data was not retrieved in time`
- I tried adding a shared folder to literally anything on the Host machine, but I am unable to get the virtual drive to show up in guest. I have tried every combination of settings for the shared drive.
- I have tried using an external USB drive passthrough to the VM, except when I plug in the USB and check what USB devices I can add in virtualbox, it says `<no devices available>` (I have attempted with 6 different USBs from 2 different brands). The USB controller is enabled for the VM but is stuck at USB 1.1 (OHCI).
- The network adapter does not work at all (any of the NIC types) because Windows does not have the drivers for any of them (I assume they are in vbox additions.)
- I tried installing the Intel 100 MT Drivers manually but they failed with the error: `Drivers for the installed Intel Ethernet network devices were not detected. Please ensure you have downloaded and installed the driver package from Intel or system manufacturer and try again.`

This is extremely frustrating. Virtualbox was working so well for years and now it all comes crashing down.

I just need a way to pull a SINGLE ZIP file off the guest OS that contains irreplaceable documents. Since I cannot even open the documents I cant hand-jam the information out either. At this point I think somehow manually parsing the VMDK is more viable...

This is the punishment for lack of backups.

Comment: Virtualbox has never been a reasonable tool for running business workloads. Some home experiments, maybe... So this question belong to SuperUser at best. However, the "parsing" idea is the good, you even don't need to do this manually. For instance, using `qemu-nbd` in Linux you can mount a disk image right away as if it was a real hard drive, even read-write, and access all the data inside. Also, in Windows, you can try to convert vmdk into vhd (probably with `qemu-img`), modern Windows should be able to mount a VHD.

Comment: Have you checked the underlying hard disk/ssd is Ok?Before trying anything else id bitcopy the entire drive.  (Id personally use ddrescue as it shows how much has been recovered and allows retrys etc but ymmv)

Comment: What is the format of the VM backing disk? (vdo? vdmk?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the .vdi file with poweriso and copy the files to your desktop.

https://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/open-vdi-file.htm

Here are some more options: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/access-virtual-hard-disks-easily-in-windows-7/

If you want even more options, just google "open .vdi files", there are plenty programs that can do that that aren't virtualbox.